# installing packages using pip and pip3 throws an error

Tags: scp, ubuntu-18.04, python3, pip, linux-terminal

I need to install python library scp and setuptools for a script but when I try to download any package using pip or pip3 it throws this error.

`ubuntu@ubuntu:~/testcommander/tests$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade --proxy=http://proxy.cat.com:80 setuptools
The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 487, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install, finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 428, in _check_skip_installed
    req_to_install, upgrade_allowed)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 405, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 303, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 197, in proxy_manager_for
    **proxy_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 440, in proxy_from_url
    return ProxyManager(proxy_url=url, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 385, in __init__
    proxy = parse_url(proxy_url)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/url.py", line 199, in parse_url
    raise LocationParseError(url)
urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError: Failed to parse: proxy.cat.com:80`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

**The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.**